# Replacing an element of a zooreg object

Tags: r, zoo

When calculating the returns of a time series of stock prices, it returns `Inf` values for some dates. The series has a zooreg class and I am trying to replace those `Inf` with `NAs`.

For reproducibility, suppose I have the following object:

```
a <- structure(c(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, Inf, Inf, 3, 4), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
  c("a", "b", "c")), index = structure(c(5113, 5144, 5173), class = "Date"), 
  frequency = 1, class = c("zooreg", "zoo"))
```

I tried the following

```
a[[a=Inf]]<-NA
```

but it gave an error:

> Error in a[[a = Inf]] <- NA : attempt to select more than one element

How do I coerce the `Inf` to `NA` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a[] <- replace(coredata(a), !is.finite(a), NA)
```

giving:

```
> a
           a  b  c
1984-01-01 1  2 NA
1984-02-01 2  4  3
1984-03-01 3 NA  4
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using `!is.finite` instead of `is.infinite`?

Comment: Either would be ok but !is.finite would also replace NaN.